# Connect Unity3d to Database? (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, unity-game-engine

I'm looking around for the easiest solution of how to connect to mysql database and for example, retrieve and update data. I've tried doing my research, but I couldn't find anything really. I mean, I would bet there's a simple way. I've worked with PHP before and I would think that its relatively easy to connect to database using C#.

Can anybody please show me a sample code of how to connect to mysql database? Also, how to retrieve and update data? Please and thank you!

Comment: Not sure if I am missing something here.. but you searched the internet and you could not find any logic?

Comment: @Ajjo as of, easy solution without extra f*ckery. I know for a fact that there's a way to connect without any extra libraries and what not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by easy, but I've used www form.

Followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EByl95OMG2o&t=80s) tutorial series from youtube to begin.

In short; you will create www forms and send required data to php code. With the answer from php code you can do your tasks. I will try to provide an example.

> Unity C# Login Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoginScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject inputUsernameText;
    public GameObject inputPasswordText;

    public string inputUsername;
    public string inputPassword;

    public string userUsername;
    public string userPassword;
    public string[] userDataArray;

    string loginURL ="YOUR LOGIN PHP CODE URL HERE" ;


    public bool isLoginButtonPressed;

    void Awake() {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (isLoginButtonPressed) 
        {
            StartCoroutine(loginToDB (inputUsername, inputPassword));
            isLoginButtonPressed = false;
        }

    }

     IEnumerator loginToDB(string username, string password)
    {

        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("usernamePost", username);
        form.AddField("passwordPost", password);

        WWW www = new WWW (loginURL, form);
        yield return www;
        //Debug.Log (www.text);


        userDataArray = userEkipIDString.Split ('|');

        userUsername = userDataArray [0];
        userPassword = userDataArray [1];
        isLoginButtonPressed = false;

        SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenuScene", LoadSceneMode.Single);




    }

    public void loginButtonPressedFunc()
    {
        inputUsername = inputUsernameText.GetComponent<Text> ().text.ToString ();
        inputPassword = inputPasswordText.GetComponent<Text> ().text.ToString ();
        isLoginButtonPressed = true;
    }




}
```

What this script does is, it get a username and password from Unity's input field and send it to php code. If username and password is correct it loads another scene.

> PHP Code

```
<?php

    $servername = "YOUR HOST NAME ex:localhost";
    $username = "YOUR DB USER NAME";
    $password = "YOUR DB PASSWORD";
    $dbName = "YOUR DB NAME";

    $user_username = $_POST["usernamePost"];
    $user_password = $_POST["passwordPost"];

    //Make Connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbName);

    //Check Connection
    if(!$conn)
    {
        die("Connection Failed. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    //else echo ("Connection Success.");

    $sql ="Select user, pass  from "YOUR TABLE NAME" where user = '".$user_username."' ";  //You can write your own query here
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    //Get the result and confirm login

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        //show data for each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            if($row['pass'] == $user_password)
            {
                //echo "Login Success";
                echo "".$row['user']."|".$row['pass']."" ;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Wrong Password";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "User not found";
    }

?>
```

You can adjust this logic to insert, update and delete

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Although you're trying to help and I appreciate that, YouTube tutorials are often the worst place to go to for advice and that goes doubly for anything that must be secure. This might seem like a trival thing ("It's just a test!") but code like this has a way of going live without being properly reviewed and this could get cracked wide open in seconds, it's full of holes. It's the kind of code you should never write in the first place, it's dangerous simply existing. This is the equivalent of saying "Surgery is easy, just wash your hands and start cutting!"

Comment: @tadman thanks for the advice, I'll check on them. And you are right about the ''test'' phase. Still learning to improve things.